# Problem with importing DAE file

Tags: import, collada

I tried to import a DAE file but THIS happened. WHY...?

[image]

Comment: did you scale the object down after importing?

Comment: Looks like parenting issues, most probably caused by transforms that were not applied in the original file, do you see all the parenting lines? I believe it's a problem with the export procedure, not the import, you need to fix the scale of the original file, apply modifiers and transforms...etc. then re-export DAE file.

Comment: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this